Can PCB trace inductance be reduced by tinning a trace?
I am creating a circuit for a "high current" buck converter (maybe 40 A), and switch node ringing is giving me a headache trying to find solutions. The circuit schematic I'm using is like this one from All About Circuits : 
(https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/dc-dc-buck-converter-design-tips-and-tricks/)
Snubbers seem to be the most effective, but they are pretty inefficient so I'd like to not rely on them if I don't have to. To switch 40 A in 15 ns to make it fast enough for the 100 kHz-1 MHz switching that most buck converters experience causes ringing with a magnitude of 21 V for 8 nH of track inductance (about an inch), and that is wildly unacceptable for pretty much any voltage range. Obviously the first thing to do is to reduce trace length for this area, but aside that, there doesn't seem like much can be done aside from increasing track width (which can only increase so far).
I was wondering if tinning a PCB trace (like most DIY'ers would do to get higher current out of a smaller trace) would cause a decrease in inductance? These formulas and diagram given from Cadence at (https://resources.system-analysis.cadence.com/blog/msa2021-is-there-a-pcb-trace-inductance-rule-of-thumb) along with most other formulas I've seen indicate that inductance is reduced with trace thickness, so what is preventing someone from removing the solder mask of a trace and thickening the trace with solder to reduce inductance? Am I thinking about this the wrong way, or is it just that simple? 

To switch 40A in 15nS what? How? The inductor's ripple current ramps up and down during on and off times of the switches. Why do you think the current will swing by 40 A in 15 ns even for 1 MHz switching frequency?

@RohatKılıç Consider 40A the inductor current. It will be switched from one FET to the other in e.g. 15 ns. This means that the FETs will experience di/dt of 40A/15ns. But not the inductor of course.

The inductance functions shown are gross simplifications, and only true within a defined range of inputs, and output error (probably 10% given the simplicity?).

The critical box is drawn too large. It need only contain the two FETs, and importantly, C1, and all the traces making up the FETs/C1 connections. The inductance of the trace from FETs to L0 just becomes lost as part of L0's effective inductance.

The resistance of tin is much higher than that of copper. Tinning a trace does not decrease the resistance very much. For 40 A you need a PCB with thick copper plating, 70 or 105 µm instead of only 35 µm.

@Neil_UK Yeah the box is on the big side cause I ripped it off a website. The inductances actually do not add to total inductance of the inductor as nice as that would be. When the top FET turns off, the inductor has to keep drawing/forcing current from SOMEWHERE, so it forces it from the bottom FET. When the top fet stops conducting, any remaining trace up to the junction with the bottom FET experiences a di/dt of 40A/15nS. The inductance is in the 8nH range for 1 inch of trace, which is 21v ringing. The phenomenon is known as switch node ringing, and its worth a Google. Very interesting.

In the answer that follows, I am assuming that the formulas referenced in the OP do not account for skin affect, since there is no frequency term in those equations.
Thickening the traces will not buy you very much at your switching times, 15 ns.  This is because the skin depth at 20 MHz (a rough approximation your 15 ns signal) is ~15 um, about the thickness of 0.5 oz copper.   So thickening the traces will not help much with inductance.
To reduce inductance, you want to increase the surface area, which can more easily be achieved by making the traces wider (fatter), rather than going to heavier weight copper or by tinning.

Consider the thickness of the tinning and compare to the trace. Now remember that inductance does not go down in proportion as trace thickness goes up. So this means that your ringing will still be present with little or no improvement.

Intuitively it makes sense that inductance wouldn't go down for an increase in conductor size, but most of the equations describing PCB inductance have a thickness (T) term and so I was wondering if anything special was going on there. The intuition for these PCB equations eludes me.

As another answer says, adding tinning will not be particularly effective.
What could be effective is

Reducing the height of the track above its reference plane (decreasing the loop area for the track and its return path)

Increasing the track width (or even using a polygon pour instead of a track).


Both of these points are supported by the equations you quoted, which shows the inductance being proportional to \$\ln\left(\frac{aH}{bW+cT}\right)\$. Reducing H or increasing W both reduce this term. Increasing T is not effective because typically \$T\ll W\$, so that changes in T have only a small effect on the total denominator.

Thanks for the Input! Yeah the reason I went for T is because any amount of solder added after the fact is going to make T orders of magnitude larger than it was before, which would affect inductance if those equations were to be believed.
Are you saying that because T is typically way smaller than W, its effect when greatly increased will make this model inaccurate?

@theph, no, I'm saying that mathematically 1/(w+t) doesn't depend strongly on t when w>>t. It's also possible the model would become inaccurate when t is near the same magnitude as w, but that would be a separate (and unrealistic) issue.

Graphing the above equation shows that you don't gain much in reducing the trace inductance by increasing the trace thickness. The following graph is normalized to 1 ounce copper thickness.

Layout of switching power supply boards is critical, especially high current switchers. Look in to the layout and see if you can improve it regarding the high current input and output paths.

Thanks for your comment! Yes layout is very critical for power supplies and other high power devices, I suppose I hadn't considered that the term becomes less useful the thicker it gets. My concern is with two components that can't be placed any closer because of size, is there any other methods than just making the trace wider. This helps a lot, thanks!
